# updating asp.net mvc web app: Can I simply update one DLL in bin/?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-7

I have an asp.net mvc (1.0) app in production (IIS7.5, W2008), and need to update one of my data classes.

Can I simply replace the existing DLL with the new one?  Do I need to restart IIS, or will it get reloaded automatically?

Answer (score 3):

MVC apps are just specially tuned web applications at heart so this will work presuming you aren't missing any other changes.

The app itself will "bounce" and some people might lose in-process sessions, but it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: I don't think 'some people might lose in-process sessions'. App Domain will be reloaded but only after ASP.NET finishes processing existing requests. All new requests should be queued.

Comment: You won't loose the session within a request, but if the App Domain recycles between a request, you can easily loose the session data then.